# Weird issues with Clang and C++, and uniform initialization

Tags: c++, xcode, clang

I was attempting to compile and run the example on this page that explores function pointers as a function input. The example I was running was the 66 line one about halfway down the page.

https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/function-pointers/

I am on Mac iOS 12.3.1. I tried to compile with

```
g++ sort.cc
```

and was getting errors that no semicolons were in my for loops, i believe due to the bracket initialization throughout the code. And when I run it with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 sort.cc
```

It works fine.

BUT

Shouldn't my clang be compiling at at least C++11? running

```
clang -v
```

I get

```
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.4.0
```

And from what I can tell clang versions past 4 default to c++14.

Also, when I run using clang or gcc I get errors setting -std=c++xx, but it works fine with g++. But as far as I can tell, g++ and gcc are aliases to clang, and running gcc -v or g++ -v gives me clang version 13.1.6.

So whats going on?

Comment: This question really isn't so much about programming as it is about defaults in Apple's clang. You'd probably be better off asking here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You've linked to the code you're referencing, but it would help people trying to help you if you could include the code in the question directly so they don't have to search for it.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode clang defaults to C++98. Compiling a simple program which has C++11 or later features will tell you that C++11 or later isn't the default. e.g.,

```cpp
// a.cpp 
constexpr int i = 10;
```

```sh
clang a.cpp -c 
a.cpp:1:1: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
constexpr int i = 10;
^
1 error generated.
```

while `clang a.cpp -c  -std=c++11` works fine.

Also see: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/CompilerSelection